# Disable application after expiry date for trial

Tags: c++, c, windows, security

I am writing a simple application for a semi-trusted client, and have no say on certain specifics. The client must be given a copy of a binary, `myTestApp`, which makes use of proprietary code in an external library, `libsecrets`. It is a Windows application that will run on a few separate Windows 7 laptops. I have been informed that after the application has served its purpose, it will be deleted. I know there is no perfect solution to this, but I would like to implement an expiry date in the program, and hinder efforts to potentially reverse engineer the code, or at least to prevent the contents of `libsecrets` from being exposed too easily.

So, my first step will be to statically link `myTestApp` against `libsecrets` so everything is contained in one binary, so only the needed pieces of `libsecrets` is included in the final binary, and its interfaces are no longer published.

Second, I want to implement some sort of `getTime` mechanism that is not naive. Is there anything in Windows that does a "secure" `getTime` call, so it can't be tricked by changing the time in the system tray or the BIOS?

Thirdly, if there is no "secure" `getTime` call, I could also modify `myTestApp` to use NTP to query a trusted time server, and fail if it can't get the time from it or the trial period has elapsed. But this could be fooled by messing with DNS on the gateway, unless there is some sort of certificates mechanism in place to verify the time server. I don't know much about this though, and would need some suggestions on how to implement it.

Next, is there some way to alter the binary so that it is impractical for individuals to attempt to reverse engineer it by viewing the assembly code? Maybe some sort of wrapper that encrypts the binary and requires a third-party authentication tool? Or maybe some sort of certificate I create that is required to run it and expires later?

Finally, is there any software out there (ie: packaging or publishing software) that can do this for me, either by repacking the final `.exe` or as some sort of plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio?

Thank you all in advance.

---

Edit: This is NOT meant to be a bullet proof system, and if it fails, that is acceptable. I just want to make it inconvenient for a non-technical person to attempt to crack. The people using it are technical Luddites, and the only way the software would be cracked is if they hired someone to do it. Since the names and company name are watermarked into the application, and only one person could benefit from its use, it's unlikely they would redistribute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make things complete secure, but you can make it hard(er).

Packing with [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) adds some level of complexity to the hacker.

You can check at runtime if you're running under a debugger in several places or if you're running under a virtual machine.

You can encrypt a DLL you're using and load it manually (complicated).

You can write a loader that checks a hash of your application and your application can check the hash of the loader.

You can get the system time and compare it to a system time you already wrote to disk and see that it's monotonic.
All depends on the level of protection you want.

If you go to PirateBay or any other torrent site, you'll see that everything get's hacked if hackers are interested.

Comment: Note also that obfuscation techniques like this (especially when it's a packer that isn't vanilla UPX) are a sure-fire way to set off false positives from anti-virus.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to make it really difficult for them to use it after expiry. The main theme of this trick is to make your expiration date independent of system time and make it depend on hours passed, irrespective of whatever the system time may be.

you will have to create a separate thread to perform this task.

Suppose you want the application to expire after they use it 70 hours.

Create a binary file called "record", and store any number in it, which should be hard to guess (I will tell you latter why you have to put this number in binary file).

When your application starts, it checks if that number is present there if yes, your application should get the current time, and  store it in that file along with hour=1 (replacing the already present number), and the thread you created should keep on checking if hour in system time has changed or not, when it changes store current time in that file along with hour=2. A time will come when hour=70.

Add this code at two places inside that thread and on the start of your applicaiton

```
/*the purpose of storing current time is to find out later if hour has changed or not*/
/*read hour from file.*/
if(hour==70)
{
    cout<<"Your trial period has expired"<<endl;
    return EXIT_SUCESS;  
}
```

now when ever hour=70 application will not work.

Earlier I told you to keep any number in your binary file, when ever they will run your application, binary file will be read and if that number is found there your application will replace it with current time and hour=1, now suppose they use your application for 5 hours and close it and run it after some time, now when your application will be run it will check that binary file if that number has been replaced with  time stored previously and hour=5 it means now you will have to store current time along with hour=stored hour in file +1; . In this even if they change time or do anything else it will not effect your expiration period. Because now your expiration checking is not based on system time any more, it is now based on hours passed, irrespective whatever the time may be.

The absence of that number indicates file is not being accessed for first time and currently present hour in file should be incremented, and use binary file so that client can't see that number.

One last thing
Your binary file's format should be like this

```
current time, hour="any number", another_secret_number
```

another_secret_number will be placed so that even if they any how change your binary they will not be able to put that another_secret_number there because they don't know it. It means while reading your binary file you will have to make sure that, the end of any entry in your binary file contains "another_secret_number" at end.

For checking purposes both hidden numbers will also be hard coded in your code, which surely they can't see, and they can't read the binary also, so there is no way they can know them.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: If anything is unclear in my answer, you can ask me. I will explain it

Comment: Even though you might think otherwise, this solution is far from safe. Easy attack: Just backup the "secret" file and restore it whenever necessary. Better: Wrap the app in a script that restores the "secret" file before starting the app. If I'm unsure where the secret file is, `strace` will tell me. Also, you can bet on unelapsed files being around when the first copies expire - ample amount of possible restore sources. I wouldn't even need to reverse engineer your app one bit to hack this scheme. (I won't be the one to do it though, hacking is against my code of conduct.)

Comment: @cmaster I was thinking of that too.

Comment: Actually we should use all possible methods we know to secure our data/application. So, along with other methods already discussed on this page, this trick will work as a plus. All methods are breakable what we can do is to add as much possible security checks as possible, and this trick is also a security check. and chances are very low that client will know name of the binary file, or will have  any idea about it.

Comment: @Taimour "chances are very low that client will know name of the binary file" - I'd say: Chances are very high that someone in the company can find out, after all, you need to install the file along with the program. People get very smart where money is involved. And I'll add another argument against such "security" schemes: Each will reduce the usability of your application a bit. With your time tracking scheme it's that the app won't run from a write protected medium without installing first, requiring sysadmin priviledges. Add a few more checks, and you seriously annoy your users.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stop the hackers!!!
Your question is like a a searching needle at the hay.
Assembly is large room for the responses.
You may thing only hrder, nothing, never stop 'bad' persons.

- For UPX: Is well known, dont use it!!!